# Jackson JSON: Unmarshalling a Map<String,Object> of attributes back into its original class

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, jackson, unmarshalling

I'm using a third-party library ([Elasticsearch 2.3.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.3), to be exact) which already parses a given JSON structure into a `Map<String,Object>` instance for me, and I want to create an instance of the class of the object which was originally marshalled into JSON:

1. **Marshalling:** `MarshallableObject` → `marshalled_object.json`
2. **Unmarshalling:** `marshalled_object.json` → `Map<String,Object>`  → `MarshallableObject`)

Additionally, here is some example code illustrating the logic:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public final class AttrMapUnmarshallingTest {

    /**
     * This class was directly used in the process for creating JSON documents indexed by Elasticsearch
     */
    public static final class MarshallableObject {

        public String bar;

        public String foo;

    }

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        try (final TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 9300))) {

            final SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("news").setTypes("article")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("text", "advertisement")).execute().actionGet();
        final Stream<Map<String, Object>> attrMaps = Arrays.stream(response.getHits().getHits())
                .map(hit -> hit.sourceAsMap());
        final Stream<MarshallableObject> objs = attrMaps.map(attrMap -> {
            // TODO: Find way of converting attr map into original class
            // which was marshalled into JSON
            // final MarshallableObject obj = OBJECT_MAPPER.read(attrMap);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some reading on the `SearchHit` class, and this is what I think may work:

```
Stream<MarshallableObject> objs = Arrays.stream(response.getHits().getHits())
    .filter(hit->hit.hasSource()) // For some reason source could be null.
    .map(hit->
         OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(hit.sourceAsString(), 
                                 MarshallableObject.class));
```

Note: You need to declare the `MarshallableObject` class `static` to make the reading work. Apparently, the hidden `ParentClass$this` reference cannot be reconstructed from the json string.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the `org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit.getSourceAsString()` method and was hoping it was possible to re-use the map. I suppose maybe not...

Comment: **Note from the distant future:** Since it seems not possible to use the `Map` created by the `SearchHit` class, it's probably better to use `SearchHit.sourceRef()` for unmarshalling because `sourceAsString()` actually calls the former method but then in fact does its own JSON processing on the result of `sourceRef()` in order to create a string.